# Libraries for embedded Tomcat via Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jms, tomcat7

With the following settings

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <port>9090</port>
          <path>/</path>
          <contextFile>src/main/resources/config/tomcat/context.xml</contextFile>
          <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>start-tomcat</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>                   
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shutdown</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
 </plugin>
```

When I ran

```
mvn install tomcat7:run-war-only
```

I got the following error

```
...Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/ConnectionFactory...
```

Putting jms.jar which contains javax/jms/ConnectionFactory into target\tomcat\lib does not solve the problem, how else can I ask javax for this embedded tomcat?

I have struggling with this for a long time, any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use `<dependencies></dependencies>` inside of your plugin?

Comment: @ujulu Thanks a lot! That solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use  inside of the plugin as @ujulu suggested :)